# Is there a command to empty datatables in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable, command

I´m new to rails and i try to def a command to delete a datatable. My idea is:

```
 def delete_old_plan

@requests = Request.all
@requests.each { |req|
  req.firstname=nil
  req.name=nil
  req.period.name=nil
  req.zahlungsbereitschaft=nil
  req.fuehrerschein=nil
  req.ausbildung=nil
  req.deutsch=nil
  req.englisch=nil
  req.save
}

flash.now[:success] = "Die Zuordnung der Nannys wurde gelöscht!"

render 'static_pages/home'
 end
```

If i do it like this he deletes all values of the requests but not the whole rows in the datatables. Is there a command to reset the whole datatable?

Comment: The above code will delete the values but keep each records in the database. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes i want to delete the whole datatable "request". It should be completly empty after the command.

Comment: Please update the question, deleting a table and emptying it are totally different operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
Request.destroy_all
```

This will delete all records in the table.

Comment: Glad I can help! If you could accept my answer, it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all records with `.destroy_all`:

```
def delete_old_plan
  @requests = Request.all
  @requests.destroy_all
  #...
end
```

Comment: destroy_all is called on a class, not a collection or array

Comment: @Jeremie That's not correct, it can be used both ways, on the class and on an enumerable e.g. `Request.where(id: 1..100).destroy_all`